# My servlet returns a blank page and does not fetch data from database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I write a simple servlet program in eclipse.i create a database name ideationportal and try to fetch data from that database.but servlet returns blank page.please help me to get out of this problem.

my jsp contains following form code

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
<p>User ID <br><input type="text"  id="username" name="uname" placeholder="username"  size="52" ><br/> <br/>
Password<br><input type="password"  id="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password" size="52"><br/><br/></p>
<input type="submit"  value="Login" size="40"><br/>
</form>
```

my servlet conatains following code

```
package com.control;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");


        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ideationportal","root","");
            Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
            String selectsql="SELECT first_name,last_name FROM master_employee_table";
            ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(selectsql);

            while(rs.next())
            {


                if(uname.equals(rs.getString("username")) && pwd.equals(rs.getString("pass")))
                {
                    out.println(rs.getString("first_name")+"");
                    out.println(rs.getString("last_name"));
                }
                else
                {
                    out.println("failed");
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try action="/Login" in your form tag.

Comment: @thamizhselvan anbu show your browser console what is the error

Comment: now i changed to .equals but still return blank page AJ.

Comment: there  is no error in my breowser console and it returns blank page. @Make

Comment: I tried that /Login but my browser told that resource not located @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: Which web server are you using for deployment .. check whether youur project is properly deployed or not and show your web.xml also

Comment: tomcat apache7.0

my web.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <display-name>csc project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>   @BrijeshBhatt

Comment: Try changing the exception in catch block like this and see if there is any exception on console .. catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();out.print(e);}